# How do I get DOT to display an image for a node?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am not having success displaying an image at a node in dot.

My node is defined:

```
SW103 [image="swOpen.png"]
```

I can view `swOpen.png` so I think the file is ok, and it is in the same directory as the code. But dot displays the node using its label "SW103", not as the image.

The documentation mentions that the image file should have size information in it, but I don't know what to put in it.

Could someone point me to an actual example that displays a .png or .bmp file as a node? (include the image file, if I need to add sizing to it)

Comment: Does running your `dot` command with the `-v` switch provide any useful information?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using a graphviz snapshot from May 2011 (2.29), the following syntax

```
digraph g{
  imgnode[image="apple-touch-icon.png", label=""];
}
```

results in

[image: graphviz output]

You'll need to set an empty label to prevent the node name from being displayed.

If this is not working for you, you may check the output of dot (something like `dot -Tpng -o graph.png graph.gv`) - if dot can't find the image, you should be able to see an error message.

I did not have to specify any size (I think this is for svg).

Comment: I'm getting NSInvalidArgumentException if I give a correct path of image or else no image error

Comment: @SaileshKotha Maybe we should specify [`image`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/image/) not `imagenode`, also specify [`imagepath`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/imagepath/).

Answer (score 1):

For one node you can use the below sample:

```
xxx.node(SW103 , color='red', image="swOpen.png")
```

It changed image of **SW103** node.