# NetworkX node_shape from svg

Tags: python, networkx

Is it possible to use an svg image to create a custom node in Networkx? For example:

Using this svg image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Firefox_Logo%2C_2017.svg

And in peudocode:

```
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_shape=svg_string)
```

And end up with something like this:

[image]

How could this be done?

Comment: Matplotlib does not support import of vector graphics so combining SVG files and matplotlib graphs is a pain (though strictly speaking possible via [svg-utils](https://github.com/btel/svg_utils). How important is using figures in SVG format to you? Would a rasterized format like a PNG file also work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the Graph to Dot [1](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot.html).
2. Draw the node as an image. [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073115/how-do-i-get-dot-to-display-an-image-for-a-node).

Comment: for #1 I could do `P = nx.nx_pydot.to_pydot(G)`.  How would I get to #2? The link referenced seems outside python.