# How to use custom image as shape in DiagrammeR package?

Tags: r, diagrammer

Is it possible to use custom shapes with Diagrammer? I've unsucessufully tried to set a path `'img/figure.png'` instead of `box`.

```r
DiagrammeR::grViz("

digraph reprex {

  # a 'graph' statement
  graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

  # several 'node' statements
  node [shape = box, # could be 'img/image.png'? ###########################
        fontname = Helvetica]
  A; B; C; D; E; F

  node [shape = circle,
        fixedsize = true,
        width = 0.9] // sets as circles
  1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8

  # several 'edge' statements
  A->1 B->2 B->3 B->4 C->A
  1->D E->A 2->4 1->5 1->F
  E->6 4->6 5->7 6->7 3->8
}
")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073115/how-do-i-get-dot-to-display-an-image-for-a-node maybe useful

Comment: @user20650 wasn't :(

Comment: https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/295

Comment: So it's a big no for now...

Comment: without writing some custom JavaScript it looks like it. Are you needing this for a web app -- as it if is for a stationary document then graphviz will work directly.